# How do I convert open street map export to geojson?

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson

I am trying to render [this](http://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/map?bbox=-90.2427,29.8859,-89.9389,30.0459) output from open street map into geojson to add into a map. I only need to export the data one time. How do I do that? OSM lists it as a [use case](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo). I see a [js library](https://gist.github.com/tecoholic/1396990) to do this (but I need a backend solution). It also [seems like](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo/GeoJSON) you can export it as geojson from the api somehow. How do most people usually do this?

Comment: [out:json] gives overpass json not geojson. But there is an option in overpass turbo to export as geojson.

Comment: Please keep in mind that this isn't an appropriate way to add a OSM map, this only makes sense e.g. if you filter to highlight roadnetwork etc.  
Please refer www.switch2osm.org

Comment: You might want to think about marking some of the questions that you've got answers to as "answered".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways

1. overpass turbo has on option to export as geojson.
2. JOSM also has option to export as geojson.
3. OpenLayers can directly read OSM format to be displayed in map. (you can also use it to convert to geojson but the above methods are much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the page about [converting map data between formats](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Converting_map_data_between_formats) in the OSM wiki. It lists two converters, [OSM2GEO](https://gist.github.com/tecoholic/1396990) and [osmtogeojson](https://github.com/tyrasd/osmtogeojson). The second one seems to support more features and is the one used by [overpass turbo](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo).